# How to declare a fallback function?

Tags: solidity

Simple question but I couldn’t find the answer in the documentation.

How do I declare a fallback function in my contract ?

Comment: @Ismael **it doesn’t describe how to declare such function** but explain what it does.

Comment: The top (only) answer states, with reference to the relevant documentation: "If the contract is meant to receive Ether with simple transfers, you should implement the fallback function as: `function() payable { }`".

Comment: Documentation is here: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html?highlight=fallback#fallback-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is easy.

```
function () payable public{
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: so it's about using the`payable`keyword, isn’t it ?

Comment: The payable keyword allows the function to receive ether.